# How to set the "weak password" error strings of a membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, web-config

I have a membership provider in my web.config with the `passwordStrengthRegularExpression` attribute set. I dropped an `asp:CreateUserWizard` in a page and tried to create a user with a weak password (ie didn't match the regex in the web.config). The validation fails and displays the message

> Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1.

The message corresponds to the default password strength requirement. I know it's using the value I have set in the web.config to validate against but how do I change/set/override the error message that gets displayed when the validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateUserWizard` control has a property called [PasswordRegularExpressionErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard_members.aspx) that you can set.

Comment: That only works if I set the PasswordRegularExpression property on the CreateUserWizard control. I was hoping to be able to only have to set the regex at the membership provider and then have it enforced for all create/edit password attempts.